# Size of brackets containing subscripts with descender

Tags: subscripts, parentheses

When placing `a_j` in `\left(`...`\right)`, the dynamic parentheses scale to `bigl(`...`bigr)`.

[image: left-hand side parentheses are smaller than right-hand side ones]

How can I tell LaTeX to treat subscript j (and J, f, g, p, q, y) as if it had no descender? I'm using LyX which is the reason for all the `\left(`...`\right)` stuff. Just using `(`...`)` makes formulas much harder to edit.

I know that I could use `\left(a_{\smash[b]{j}}\right)_{\smash[b]{j}}`, but I don't want to modify every equation.

Note: Computer Modern Math and Latin Modern Math don't have that problem for whatever reason. In any other math fonts I tried (e.g. Euler, Kurier, or Libertine) it does exist.

I've found [\left[ and \right] resizing differently for very similar formulae. Don't know how to fix it.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290529/left-and-right-resizing-differently-for-very-similar-formulae-dont-know-ho/290531) and [Subscripts after a macro for \left( and \right) parentheses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251127/subscripts-after-a-macro-for-left-and-right-parentheses) which solve the problem partially.

Comment: using `\left\right` here is wrong anyway you get unwanted horizontal space as well as the wrong size delimiter, just use `(a_i)`

Comment: If you can't avoid `\left` and `\right` with LyX, then it's time to leave it alone and type in the code yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid running into autosizing issues, while still being able to place the outer index well below the inner index, write

```
(a_i{)}_i
```

and

```
(a_j{)}_j
```

Encasing the `)` symbol in curly braces serves to change its math “status” from math-close to math-ord which, in turn, influences how the outer subscripts are placed.

A full MWE (note the relative positions of the outer subscripts):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{palatino,eulervm} % to mimic the "look" of the OP's screenshot
\begin{document}
$(a_i{)}_i$ vs.\ $(a_i)_i$

\medskip
$(a_j{)}_j$ vs.\ $(a_j)_j$
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is simply wrong, sorry.

Comment: The placement of the subscript doesn't depend on the type of the atom. In the second case, the subscript is to a subformula: try `$(a_i\mathord)_j$` and see.

Comment: @egreg: It appears to matter whether one writes `\mathord)` or `\mathord{)}`. I just posted an MWE to illustrate my earlier, somewhat terse answer.

Comment: Yes, of course: `\mathord)` doesn't create a subformula, `\mathord{)}` does. Which is *exactly* the point.

Comment: @egreg - (Just got back from the TUG conference banquet dinner.) I continue to believe that the main point of my answer is about the difference in placement of the subscript `i`,  depending on whether one writes `$)_i$` or `${)}_i$`. If the latter expression entails "creating a subformula", I have no quarrel with that.